# Remove Letters from a row

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a GPS truck tracking DB i am working with and I want to remove all the Letters from a certain column. Or if it is easier extrapolate all the Numbers and put them in their own column. The Left, Right, Mid will not work because the numeric value for each number position changes line to line.[Screen Shot of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgOdx.png)
I am not sure this is even possible in access or if I will have to pass the data through python to do what I am wanting.

Comment: From which column in your example? All three? There are two ways to do this: (a) parse the string based on the delimiter (i.e. a comma or space); or (b) loop thru the string character by character and keep only numbers. I can give an example if needed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
InStr( startPosition, "abcdefg", "c" )
```

returns the character position of "c" in "abcdefg", 0 if no match.

Either use vba to programmatically process the records or use queries directly but not as efficient. 
ex. (step by step to make it clearer)

```
SELECT IIf( InStr(1,[description],"odo:")>0, "found", "not found" ) 
   AS Result FROM MyTable;
```

replace "found" with:

```
Mid( [description], InStr(1,[description],"odo:")+3 )
```

this will chop off everything on the left "On Duty, odo:", "Driving, odo:".

Since it is not posible to store into temporary variables in queries, just use up several InStr() to find "odo:" and possibly " Miles" then use them again to compute the length. For small number of records this will be fine, otherwise better use VBA for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The following are two methods to return only digits - but you need to tell us which field(s) you want to parse.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function Test_This()
Dim strIN   As String
    strIN = "On Duty, odo: 245678.9,"
    MsgBox "Loop Method:" & vbCrLf & "Input String: " & strIN & vbCrLf & "Output String: " & Method_Loop(strIN)
    MsgBox "Parse Method:" & vbCrLf & "Input String: " & strIN & vbCrLf & "Output String: " & Method_Parse(strIN)

End Function


Function Method_Parse(InValue As String) As String
Dim i   As Integer
Dim i2      As Integer
Dim iLen    As Integer
Dim strOut  As String
    iLen = Len(InValue)
    i2 = 0
    strOut = ""

    ' Assume delimiter is colon + space
    i = InStr(1, InValue, ": ")
    If i = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No starting delimiter (: ) for '" & InValue & "'", vbOKOnly, "No Start Delimiter"
        Method_Parse = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    i2 = InStr(i, InValue, ",")
    If i2 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No ending delimiter (,) for '" & InValue & "'", vbOKOnly, "No End Delimiter"
        Method_Parse = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    strOut = Mid(InValue, i + 2, i2 - i - 2)
    Method_Parse = strOut
End Function

Function Method_Loop(InValue As String) As String
Dim i       As Integer
Dim i2      As Integer
Dim iLen    As Integer
Dim strOut  As String

    iLen = Len(InValue)
    i2 = 0
    strOut = ""
    For i = 1 To iLen
        ' If you can have a period that is not part of the number,
        ' and your number's can have decimal places, then modify the code
        ' to check if 'IsNumeric' for the prefeeding and following characters.
        If (IsNumeric(Mid(InValue, i, 1))) Or (Mid(InValue, i, 1) = ".") Then
            strOut = strOut & Mid(InValue, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    Method_Loop = strOut

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like from that screenshot you can use:

```
X = InStr(0, Description, ":" ) 'Gets the position of the first semicolon
Y = InStr(X, Description, "," ) 'Gets the position of the following comma
```

Then you can use those two numbers in a Mid statement:

```
Z = Mid(Description, X + 1, Z - 1)
```

That should give you the odometer reading.

If you need other numbers, just continue on with that logic.